# Letter to my father from German in field hospital in Schwedzinger near Rhein 1945

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-2

At the end of the ww2 my father an American Medic was shot and captured and taken to the field hospital in Schwedzinger near Rhein Germany.  He had been on patrol with 270 men and they were all killed except for my father.  He was shot through the ankle and was in the hospital 1945? for about 6 months.  General Patton came through the town he was in on the way to Berlin and freed him.  While in the hospital he was unable to speak the language and he was taken care of very poorly.  In the bed next to him was a German by the name Werner Karstens.  I 1946 he wrote this letter to my father saying how sorry he was that he was treated so bad.  My father passed away 25 years ago and I never got much of the story out of him or if he ever wrote a letter back to Werner Karstens.

https://issuu.com/brucebyers/docs/dad-letter-46

If anyone knows of this field hospital, knows Werner Karstens or his family or any things about this I would love to talk to you or them.  i need to find out the rest of the story

Answer (score 1):

The town is Schwetzingen, near Mannheim. There is a hospital there, identified as a former county hospital. Whether that was the field hospital the letter mentions is hard to say. The hospital underwent administrative reorganization in 2006, but old records may still be kept. According to their web site, you can contact them by email at klinik-schwetzingen@grn.de.